# tshark show payload as text

Tags: pcap, tshark

I am trying to get tshark to show the payload of packages in clear text and I am failing in that. Which makes me really sad.

- tshark -r pcap -T fiels -e data (or data.text) gives blank results.
- tshark -r pcap -T fiels -e tcp.payload gives hex results.

So the question is how do I get tshark to show the tcp.payload als text (ascii).